# CKEditor configuration, prefer img tag atrributes over inline style

Tags: configuration, ckeditor

On [su](https://superuser.com/questions/137873/ckeditor-configuration-options) it was suggested to ask this here...

Looking for a way to disable a feature in CKEditor that messes with attributes height and width on my and converts them into inline styles.

The version of CKEditor is 3.2 and I have access to config files.

Along the same lines is there somewhere an overview (or procedure) for changing the way CKEditor produces html (I'd like to force it to do inline styles; except for images, plus some other changes)

Thank you for taking the time to read this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this sample: http://dev.fckeditor.net/attachment/ticket/5024/5024_5.patch

Comment: +1 without testing because it seems to do the trick and you're the author :)

Comment: It still needs some extra adjustments (at least handle better the color conversions done by Firefox) but hopefully should be published with CKEditor 3.3